# Python Optimal Group by Size

Tags: python-2.7, file, optimization, directory, grouping

Python 2.7

**Reason**: I have a directory with various top-level folders/directories and files. I need to backup these to writable DVDs. To optimize the amount of DVDs used, I would like to use Python to scan the top-level directory and then group the top-level folders and files into optimal (fewest) groupings of a certain size (~4.7GB in this case). Sure, I can sort of do this manually, but the result will not optimize the use of DVDs.

**Question**: I can write the directory scan/walk, but does anyone know of code or a module that I can use that will optimally group a list of folders/file into **optimal** predetermined size groupings?

Recommendations of open source/free Windows apps. that can accomplish this would also be welcome.

Comment: Looks like binpacking to me.

Comment: It is an NP-hard problem. So solving it optimally is very hard. But there exist good heuristics. A quick search yields [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bin-packing-problem/1.0.0) Python package.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem Good info. and just what I need for me to solve the problem.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem Feel free to provide a short answer based on your comments and I will give you credit. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the [*Bin Packing Problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) where one is given a number of items and the size of a bin. One aims to find a configuration such that every bin holds no items such that the sum of their sizes is larger than the capacity of the bin and the *number of bins* is minimized.

Your problem maps to this problem since every directory is an item, and the bins represent in this case DVDs.

The problem is a *combinatorial NP-hard* one. This means there is not much hope to find the absolute optimal solution within reasonable time. The problem is however well studied and a lot of heuristics exists that will produce good results.

A quick search on "Python bin packing" generated these libraries [`binpacking`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/binpacking) and [`bin-packing-problem`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bin-packing-problem/1.0.0). I do not claim this is the *best* library (nor do I say it is the contrary). But I'm quite confident that there exist good bin packing libraries (and probably the given one will do quite well).

Comment: For those that may see this later, the problem may also be approached from the greedy-algorithm direction as well. Being that binpacking is np-hard, at some point the greedy strategy seems to become better as the number of items to "pack" gets longer. For the sake of learning, I am going to go both ways. See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903859/optimal-combination-of-files-to-the-blocks-of-4-8gb?rq=1 Thanks again to Willem Van Onsem in getting me on the right track.